# Javascript string literal and string Object treat so wired

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am big confuse between string literal and string object type in javascript.

Here code

```
var a = new String( "aaaa" ); 
var b='adddd';

console.log(a) //String('aaaa')
console.log(b) //adddd

console.log(typeof a) //ojbect
console.log(typeof b) //string


console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call( a )) //[object String]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call( b )) //[object String]
```

The **typeof** of both string is different but when make by **toString()** it return same. Why and How????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why and How????

`Object.prototype.toString` converts the `this` value to an object value:

> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return **"[object Undefined]"**.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return **"[object Null]"**.
> 3. Let `O` be `!ToObject(this value)`.
> 4. ...

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Calling `ToObject` on a primitive string is the same as calling `new String(primitiveStringValue)`.